# Really Small Message Broker (RSMB) on windows server 2008

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008, push-notification, messagebroker

i want to ask about how to use RSMB on windows server 2008.
i use amazon as a server. and i use android as a client

when i try connect my mqtt client to server. an error ocured.

i use an simple notification based on this link. http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

it work fine when i use in local host. but when i try to connect to real server it won't work. this is the log.

```
10-25 14:26:24.820: I/DemoPushService(3952): Starting service...
10-25 14:26:24.820: I/DemoPushService(3952): Connecting...
10-25 14:26:44.730: I/dalvikvm(3952): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-25 14:26:44.750: I/dalvikvm(3952): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

this error occured when i start the service on client.

thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt this is your issue, but I might suggest using Eclipse Paho java jar instead of the older wmqtt.jar.  Also use the mqttSample.jar MQTT testing utility to verify your configuration.  It is part in the IA92 download here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24006006

here is a screenshot of the mqttSample.jar test utility

[image: th]